# JENA: Create Object Property Assertions between two individuals of different ontology classes

Tags: java, jena, owl

I am creating a OWL in rdf/xml format with jena.

I am able to create a individual for a class like below

```
OntClass wine = model.createClass(uri + "#wine")
OntClass meat = model.createClass(uri + "#meat")

ObjectProperty predicate = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase + "#goes_well_with")
predicate.addDomain(wine)
predicate.addRange(meat)

Individual whiteWine = wine.createIndividual(uri + "white_wine")
Individual redMeat = meat.creatIndividual(uri + "red_meat")

whiteWine.addRDFType(OWL2.NamedIndividual)
redMeat.addRDFType(OWL2.NamedIndividual)
```

which jena writes into a file as

```
    <!-- classes -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#wine"/>
    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#meat"/>
    <!-- object property -->
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#goes_well_with">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#wine"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#meat"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    <!-- individuals -->
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#white_wine">
         <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#wine"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#red_meat">
         <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#meat"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

now I wanted to create object property assertion between **individuals** **white_wine** and **red_meat** in jena

which will result in (below example manually created in protege)

```
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#white_wine">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#wine"/>
        <!-- this is the part I am unable to render with jena -->
        <goes_well_with rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#red_meat"/>
        <!-------------------->
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

appreciate all your help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sample code snippet which gave me the expected result.

After creating the object property **predicate** and individuals **whiteWine and redMeat** (like the code in question) just add below code using [ModelCon.add(resource,predicate,rdfNode)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/ModelCon.html#add-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode-)

```
model.add(whiteWine, predicate, redMeat)
```

or as mentioned by @ASKW in the comment

```
whiteWine.addProperty(predicate, redMeat)
```

works as well.

which results in

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.example.com/ontology#white_wine">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#wine"/>
    <goes_well_with rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/ontology#red_meat"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Now I got the result I wanted, however

1. just what did the code do?
2. did it add an assertion?
3. did it add a triple?

appreciate your help.

Comment: a property assertion is nothing more than a triple in RDF, yes. But why didn't you follow your intial code, I mean you added `rdf:type` already, so you just could have done `whiteWine.addProperty(predicate, redMeat);`

Comment: Hi @AKSW , I didn't actually know it was an option. Thanks for the suggestion I will integrate your solution into the answer as well.